# How to call Javascript function onto web content (WebBrowser maybe) in C# WinForms

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, webbrowser-control

I found several tutorials on  how to run Javascript in C# code, however, if I understood them correctly, none of them lets me do what I need.
I have a C# WinFowms app with a `WebBrowser` that loads a page. Now, I need to run some javascript **on the page** loaded in the browser, like to fill or read some textboxes values. I have managed to run JS in my app, but the JS run *standalone* regardless of what is loaded in the browser.
It would be great if I could read a textbox value in JS and pass it back to the C# app, but doesn't matter if this won't be possible, I'll find another way, like saving them to .txt file in JS and reading them in C#. First I need to get the JS running on the webpage loaded. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly

```
webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new MyForm();
string html = "<script>external.DoSomething('test');</script>";
webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
```

---

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class MyForm : Form
{
    public void DoSomething(string s)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Called from JS: " + s);
    }
}
```

another html sample calling DoSomething function (written in c#) with the value of textbox in html

```
string html = 
    "<input id=txt type=text/>" +
    "<input type=button value='click' onclick='external.DoSomething(txt.value)'/>";
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand right how to use this, but when I copied the first two parts and put a breakpoint into DoSomething method, it isnt even hit, so the function is not called at all.
Is the script launched automatically, or do I need to do something else to fire the JS added to the Document?

Comment: @MarekBuchtela above codes works correctly since I tested it before posting. I put the code related with *webBrowser1* on form_load and it worked.

Comment: My apology, it works anywhere in the code except for one method (ironically the only one where I need it), so mistake is on my side.
Thank you!